# Firefox unresponsive due to lock files, how do I remove them?

Tags: firefox

As my laptop hard rive was knackered I was adivsed to use ubuntu, it set-up perfectly. But i tried downloading *Google Chrome* and *Flash Player* because I couldnt watch any videos and now *Firefox* has become unresponsive.

It says

> Firefox is already running but it is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the exisitng firefox process or restart your system.

I tried restarting but that hasn't worked.

Ubuntu also asked me if i wanted to do a update which I did, could this be a problem also.
When I try to delete the files, it tells me the following:

> The link ''lock'' is broken. move it to the rubbish bin.
>
> This link cannot be used, because it's target '127.0.1.1;+1885'' doesn't exist

- Killing the process does not work either.

Answer (score 3):

Open the file manager and press Ctrl+H to see hidden files. GO into `.mozilla`->`firefox` and there should be one folder in there, possibly with a very weird name. Now, go into that folder and delete the files `lock` and `.parentlock` to allow Firefox to access its SQlite database.

Comment: would file manager be in file system

Comment: gone into the folder and there's 'crash reports' ido6h0pe.default and 'profiles.ini

Comment: It won't let me delete anything.

Comment: @JamesTweed Press Ctrl+H as .lock is hidden/

Comment: where's file manager

Comment: tried but failed done what you said but it's refusing to delete

Comment: @JamesTweed Please try running `ls -li` in the terminal in that folder. It'll give some useful info, most probably.

Comment: if i restart it says 'errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal (most likely with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) or use the dash).

Sometimes the process ID will change by the time you copy and paste it. You have to kill Firefox in single instance. Try this script

```
ps -aux | grep firefox | awk '{print $2}' | head -1 | xargs kill -9
```

or more simply

```
killall -s KILL firefox
```

Comment: so the number that came up is 8188 where do i put it

Comment: could you tell me the exact code to put in as it says 'invalid signal specification' am i doing it wrong

Comment: kill -9 8188 that's what you have to enter.

Comment: it say's command not found

Comment: The `kill` command was not found? If you modify what I wrote above to be `ps -u $USER -f | grep firefox | awk '{print $2}'` you can use the kill command for all those numbers.

Comment: it nows comes up 9801

Comment: It's going to keep changing numbers every time you start/stop firefox.

Comment: What happened to good ol' `killall -s KILL firefox`? No need to search the right processes by foot with `ps`, `awk`, and `grep` (which is [superfluous](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#grep) btw).

Comment: @JamesTweed I have made changes to the code, that will help issue with PID changing. Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Firefox GUI isn't visible, the process is likely still running in the background. You can see the process number with `ps -e | grep firefox` and using `kill #` to kill that process number should allow you to reopen firefox.

Comment: i done that but still unresponsive

Comment: I reread your question. Are you saying that a full reboot still results in the same message?

Comment: i've just restarted the laptop and once i restart it says there is file errors do i want to repair, i press F and it goes to the admin section. but i dont have a clue what to do from there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried killing the process with the System Monitor? In the Ubuntu Search, type "sys" and open System Monitor. Find firefox... select it, and click End Process. Hopefully this will kill the process for you and you'll be able to restart Firefox. I've been having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the process ID will change, when you copy and paste it. So you have to kill Firefox in single instance. Try this script

```
ps -aux | grep firefox | awk '{print $2}' | head -1 | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: This would be better as an edit to http://askubuntu.com/a/219437/158442.

Answer (score -1):

Do a

```
pkill firefox
```

at the terminal!

Comment: nope didnt do anything

Answer (score -3):

Then go for any newer version of Firefox by these commands.......After connecting it to internet try these commands.....

1.sudo apt-get install firefox(for firefox)

2.sudo apt-get install chromium-browser(for chrome)

3.sudo apt-get install flash-player(for flash player)

Comment: Two of those three commands have next to nothing to do with Firefox itself. "Going for a newer version" isn't a solution to the problem either. This message persists through the versions, and is fully intentional - even though it is sometimes thrown when not needed.

Comment: how do i solve it then

Comment: Ok....I got my mistake.....