# Unresponsive Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox unresponsive - Lockfiles stuck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219234/firefox-unresponsive-lockfiles-stuck)

My firefox is unresponsive: it keeps coming up with a message that says

> firefox is already running, but is not responding, to open a new window, you must first close the existing firefox process, or restart your system

now restarting the system doesn't work, does anyone know what else I can do?