# Firefox already running Issue

Tags: firefox

Firefox 23.0 canonical 1.0 already running not shutting down or starting up error.
States its already running need to shut-down do system restart and close browser.

Comment: ok.. Open your terminal and run this command `sudo pkill firefox`. Then try to run firefox again..

Comment: +1, and just `pkill firefox` should do.

Comment: if the two answers below which recommend killing the existing process do not work, because firefox *isn't* actually running, you'll want to remove the lock files as per one of the answers at http://askubuntu.com/questions/219234/firefox-unresponsive-due-to-lock-files-how-do-i-remove-them

Answer (score 7):

**In one line**:

```
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/.parentlock
```

---

**Explanations**: You need to remove the `.parentlock` file in your mozilla profile:

```
cd ~/.mozilla/firefox
ls
```

This will show you one directory with a strange name, such as `12abc34d.default`. Go to that directory and remove `.parentlock`.

Comment: This was helpful. I found that the `*.default` folder only had `root:root` permission. After deleting the .parentLock file, I could still not launch FF. I updated the permission on the `*.default` to my user and group `root`, this fixed it. FYI `chown [user]:[group] -R`

Answer (score 3):

If you like the UI route:
 1. Click the Ubuntu Logo
 2. Type "System Monitor"
 3. Find Firefox in the list of running applications, right-click and choose to kill the application

Answer (score 1):

Go to command line:

- Run this command: $ **top**
- you'll see some graphical output, then note the processID **(PID)** of firefox
- then press **'k'** to KILL the process
- you'll be asked to enter the processID **(PID)** of process you want to kill.
- Just enter the processID of the firefox, and you're ready to go ..!!

And you can use this procedure to **kill** any process.