# I can't open Firefox

Tags: firefox

I can't open Firefox. I see the message
`Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window , you must first close the existing Firefox process or restart your system.`

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your PC?

Comment: Try `killall firefox` in a terminal, and if it does not work `killall -KILL firefox`. @user300458, reboot should seldom be necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox unresponsive due to lock files, how do I remove them?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219234/firefox-unresponsive-due-to-lock-files-how-do-i-remove-them)

Comment: Try to open Firefox profile icon used to start Firefox with a text editor, look in it for -no-remote and delete that (only the "-no-remote")

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your profile is locked.

The quick way to solve it is to open the System Monitor, and kill the existing Firefox process. Then you can start a new instance.

See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/78930) on Super User.